# How to automatically load new TLS Certificates for Envoy Proxy?

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, envoyproxy, cert-manager

I'm using https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager in a Kubernetes environment to automatically load https://letsencrypt.org/. It creates certificates that expire in 90 days. [30 days](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/blob/f4e5203f1c387f4ebb52aa08f602ead5dfd048bb/pkg/apis/certmanager/v1alpha1/const.go#L32) prior to expiration, cert-manager renews the certificates and replaces the certificates. The certificates are stored in k8s secrets.

How do you get Envoy Proxy to [automatically reload the certificates](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/891)? The issues was closed and appears to be unanswered. There is some [mention](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/1194) of a Secret Discovery Service (SDS) that could help provide a solution, but I haven't been able to figure out one yet.

For nginx, it is possible to configure TLS by add the k8s secrets to k8s volumes, mounting the volume to the filesytem for nginx to use. A filesystem watcher can then be used to call [sudo nginx -s reload](https://serverfault.com/a/708779/125092) to reload the configuration when the certificates change. I see that Envoy Proxy supports [hot restart](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/envoy-hot-restart-1d16b14555b5), but I don't see a command similar to nginx to make it hot restart.

There is a [hot-restarter.py](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/restarter/hot-restarter.py), but it isn't a file watcher and I'd rather not install python on the envoyproxy/envoy:latest docker image. I thought may be some of the functionality of that program could be build in to a rust app that also does file-watching, but there has to be something that exists already for this very common scenario, right?

Comment: Hi. Did you finally find a solution about the auto cert reload ?

Comment: @ChaoxiangN I did not. I had dreams about translating hot-restarter.py to rust, but that never happened.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you are configuring (or plan to configure) Envoy using a static configuration whereas where Envoy really shines is when you supply it a dynamically generated configuration on the fly. The main difference between the two is that you have a service that you configure Envoy to regularly consult for updates but what the service would have to send back looks very similar to the static configuration.

That's what they term [*xDS*](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/the-universal-data-plane-api-d15cec7a) which encompasses different services you can write that generate different parts of the configuration. That one service (that you must supply and run) can effectively provide all the other services (e.g. Listener Discovery Service) via different endpoints that it exposes. Envoy allows you to configure it to poll a [REST-like API](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-docs/xds_protocol#rest-json-polling-subscriptions), a [streaming gRPC service](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-docs/xds_protocol#streaming-grpc-subscriptions) or even to [watch a file](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-docs/xds_protocol#filesystem-subscriptions) in a specific location (I suspect this one is the winner for you). You actually only need to implement the LDS in order to dynamically managed TLS certs. The rest of the config can remain static.

If you choose the route of writing a dynamic service that Envoy consults for config then it's not to complicated to set this up so that it just reads the contents of the files on disk and provides Envoy with whatever it finds in there. For this you could just supply an [inline string data source](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/core/base.proto#envoy-api-msg-core-datasource) for the [Common TLS Context object](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/auth/cert.proto#envoy-api-msg-auth-tlscertificate). Unless you have thousands of certificates and listeners, the response body won't get anywhere near your bandwidth/memory limits.

I'll confess that I exhausted the time I could afford getting started on Envoy in trying to interpret their extensive machine-oriented documentation so I eventually settled on a polled HTTP service for our config. Even with polling every few seconds it's the only real traffic so it's pretty easy to set up and keep going. I'll speak about this approach since that's the one I'm most familiar with. 
You might have started with something like the [static example](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/overview/v2_overview#static) but all you'd need to do to make it more dynamic is move to the [dynamic configuration](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/overview/v2_overview#dynamic) a little further down. Just substitute REST for gRPC as that's a bit easier to get going with and implement the [REST endpoints](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/overview/v2_overview#rest-endpoints) documented further down. It takes a little trial and error but a good way to get going is simply making the service return the JSON version of the config you're already using. One gotcha to look out for is that you'll need to add `"type"` and `"version"` keys on the top level JSON object that references the proto of the type of thing you're returning, i.e. the response to the LDS service might look like this:

```
{
    "version_info": "0",
    "resources": [{
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Listener",
        "name": "http_listener",
        "address": "{...}",
        "filter_chains": [{
            "filters": [
                "{...}"
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

This was not nearly as easy as I had hoped to get working in Python. They have a pretty good example in Go of the *xDS* server that uses gRPC but that didn't help me nearly as much as looking through some of the other attempts at implementing the *xDS* server I found on [Github](https://github.com/search?q=envoy+service+discovery). [This project](https://github.com/praekeltfoundation/marathon-envoy-poc/blob/master/marathon_envoy_poc/envoy.py) was particularly helpful for me. Also I'm yet to run into anything that would actually need a hot restart if you're already configuring envoy dynamically other than stable things like the cluster identifiers of the Envoy instance itself.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @jeteon's answer about using xDS and dynamic configuration, instead of using LDS and changing the listeners dynamic file everytime, you can setup the SDS and use the *watched_directory* feature. Take a look at the [key rotation section](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/security/secret#key-rotation) of Enovy documentation.